# Javascript: Waiting for an Argument to respond via Return

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a function that waits for its attribute to responde first and then continues with its process. The function call looks like this :

```
processResult(getResult());
```

The problem is, that the *getResult* function needs its time before it returns a value, because the *theResult* function offers the user a interface of three buttons and only returns a value if the user clicks on a button, the function looks like this :

```
function getResult() {
$(document.createElement('button'))
    .html("1")
    .click(function() {
      return 1;
    })
    .appendTo($(document.body));

$(document.createElement('button'))
    .html("2")
    .click(function() {
      return 2;
    })
    .appendTo($(document.body));

$(document.createElement('button'))
    .html("3")
    .click(function() {
      return 3;
    })
    .appendTo($(document.body));
}
```

The *processResult* functions looks like this, this is only an example :

```
function processResult(arg) {
  alert(arg);
}
```

The functions calls *undefinied* when I load the site, I know that this behaviour is an result of the asynchronous behavior of Javascript, but I don't know how I can improve my code, that the *processResult* functions waits for an return of the *getResult* function.

I hope you can help me, thank you

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 function getResult() {
   $(document.createElement('button'))
     .html("1")
      .click(function() {
       return 1;
      })
      .appendTo($(document.body));
      
    $(document.createElement('button'))
     .html("2")
      .click(function() {
       return 2;
      })
      .appendTo($(document.body));
      
    $(document.createElement('button'))
     .html("3")
      .click(function() {
       return 3;
      })
      .appendTo($(document.body));
  }
  
  function processResult(arg) {
   alert(arg);
  }
  
  processResult(getResult());
</script>
</head>
<body>


</body>
```

Comment: JavaScript is not inherently async unless you execute async functions - you do not have any in the code you posted. Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: `.click(function() {
      return 1;
    })` does not work. Instead do `.click(function() {
      processresult(1);
    })`

Comment: Or better: `$("#buttonContainer").on("click","button",function() { processResult($(this).text)()});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats what callbacks are for:

```
function getResult(callback) {
$(document.createElement('button'))
   .html("1")
   .click(function() {
      callback(1);
   })
.appendTo($(document.body));

$(document.createElement('button'))
  .html("2")
  .click(function() {
     callback(2);
 })
.appendTo($(document.body));

$(document.createElement('button'))
   .html("3")
   .click(function() {
      callback(3);
    })
 .appendTo($(document.body));
}
```

Then do:

```
getResult(processResult);
```

By the way, your *return* returns into the jquery functions and will do nothing...

And you may - if youve got a bigger js knowledge - have a look at js Promises. They are great...

*shortified code:*

```
function getResult(callback) {
for(var i=1;i<4;i++){
(function(i){
$(document.createElement('button'))
   .html(i+"")
   .click(function() {
      callback(i);
   })
.appendTo($(document.body));
})(i);
}
}
```

**workaround**

If you really need to stick to the ˋprocessResult(getResult());ˋ , you may do this ( not recommended):

```
function getResult() {
var main={callback:function(){}};
for(var i=1;i<4;i++){
(function(i){
$(document.createElement('button'))
   .html(i+"")
   .click(function() {
      main.callback(i);
   })
.appendTo($(document.body));
})(i);
}
return main;
}
function processResult(cb){
  cb.callback=function(a){
    //your code
  };
}
```

Comment: can cut it down even more using `$('<button>')`

Comment: thank you for your solution, but the only thing I can't modify is the call of the function, so it must be `processResult(getResult());`

Comment: @rpanske thats impossible

Comment: @Jonasw Even if its not recommended, that was the solution I was looking for, thank you, you saved me many days of work ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I would solve it differently. After you created all your buttons, just add some event listener to all of them. The function reads the HTML of the button and passes it to your function. Depending on your real-world application, you may have to tweak it a little bit. ;)

```
$('button').click(function() { processResult($(this).text()) });
```